Old fantasy movie with a sort of king feeding two princesses to a monster
Okay, this is kind of a long story. So I was about 8-12 and I was at my grandmothers house and I saw a fantasy movie on tv with horror elements, it seemed like. It looked like it was made in the 70's or 80s, it was in English, in color, and I don't remember it being cheesy.
At the beginning of the movie, some kind of a king or an authority figure was with two women, I believe he said they were princesses. He put one of them or the both of them down into a pit that supposedly had a monster or a blob like creature down inside of it, and they screamed in fear and pain as it 'consumed' them. Later on in the movie there's a scene where there's these African looking men chained together and they were being dangled over some kind of a long narrow pit with lava on the bottom of it. 
That's about all I remember... I tried asking about this on Rotten Tomatoes, but no one there helped me. If anyone could help me find or describe this movie, I'd be VERY appreciative of it. Not sure what it was called, should have wrote it down all those years ago. But it looked like a decent movie. Thank you. :)

Can you estimate the year\decade of release? The language\country of origin? Was it in color? Was it cheesy looking or not?

I'll try my best... it looked like it was made in the 70's or 80s, it was in english, and yes it was in color, and don't remember it being cheesy.

Thanks! Added those in. I think I know what you're after...

Oh thank you very much good sir. :) Should help in my search... I looked at Wikipedia pages of fantasy movie listings, and didn't find it... and haven't found it on Rotten Tomatoes either... so I'm stumped. I didn't think at the time being a young lad to write the name of it down... can't even remember what channel it was on... le sigh. The people on the Rotten Tomatoes forums weren't helpful either, I made at least three threads about it but they removed them. No idea why... :/

Sorry, I thought it was The Magic Sword from 1962 (from MST3K), but I don't think it contains that 2nd scene with the lava pit.

Oh its fine don't worry, I'll check that one out. :D

I just found it on youtube and went through bits and pieces of it, but not the same movie I had in mind. :/ Its great b-movie fantasy goodness though. :P

Are you sure it was Princesses (plural)? Dragonslayer has such a scene with medieval townspeople's virgins offered to a dragon, and a later scene with that victim being snacked on by the dragon's offspring in the lair. The true Princess offers herself up for sacrifice later when she discovers her father's (King's) deception to exclude her from the earlier lotteries.

What about Allan Quatermain and the Lost City of Gold? The city has two queens, one good (Nyleptha) and one evil (Sorais). But they are both controlled by the evil high priest, Agon. Agon dips African characters in molten gold. No one gets fed to a blob monster, but Sharon Stone does plenty of screaming in this movie, including when she falls into a pit (on two separate occasions) and is menaced by snakes, lions, and mutant bats.

Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.

The movie Dragonslayer has some of the scenes described, especially the concept of the Princesses being offered to a monster. The misconception is that the offered virginal sacrificed townspeople are dressed elegantly for the dragon to consume. Later, during the required lottery, the actual Princess offers herself in sacrifice because she discovered her father, the King, had excluded her from all earlier lotteries, the means to select the earlier victims.
The first victim shown during the film is shown later being consumed by the offspring of the dragon within its lair.
from imdb:

A King has made a pact with a dragon where he sacrifices virgins to it, and the dragon leaves his kingdom alone. An old wizard, and his keen young apprentice volunteer to kill the dragon and attempt to save the next virgin in line - the Kings own daughter.>

The film meets the time frame described for release, and was a popular film. Stars both Peter MacNicol and Caitlin Clarke in their first roles.

Yes, it is similar, but not the same movie I'm thinking of. :/ Close though. :D
